# Popover inside on Table doesn't display data

Tags: sapui5

I have this table component ([sap.m.Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Table.html)):

```
<Table
    inset="false"
    items="{
        path: '/SelectExpenseDetails'
    }" >
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar>
            <Button icon="sap-icon://cause" press="onBack" ariaLabelledBy="Atrás" />
            <Button icon="sap-icon://message-information" press="showInfoExpenseItem" ariaLabelledBy="Atrás" />
            <Title text="{i18n>GV.APROB.EXPENSES.detail.title}" level="H2"/>

        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    <columns>
        <Column width="7em" >
            <Text text="{i18n>GV.APROB.EXPENSES.detail.concepto.pago}" />
        </Column>

        <Column
            width="4em"
            demandPopin="true"
            hAlign="Center">
            <Text text="{i18n>GV.APROB.EXPENSES.detail.monto}" />
        </Column>

        <Column width="1.5em"
            demandPopin="true"
            hAlign="Center">

        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>

            <ObjectAttribute text="{ExpensesCategory}" />

            <ObjectNumber
                number="{PlanAmount}"
                unit="{masterExpense>/CurrencySymbol}" />

            <Button icon="sap-icon://comment" press="showCommentsExpenseDetailItem" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"/>                                          
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Function showCommentsExpenseDetailItem display the popover. Popover component is opened but it doen's display data:

Here is code:

```
showCommentsExpenseDetailItem: function(event){
                var popover = sap.ui.xmlfragment("la.incloud.rva.aprobaciones.view.components.popover-comment-item-detail", this);
                this.getView().addDependent(popover);
                popover.openBy(event.getSource());
            }
```

And this the XML fragment:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Popover 
        showHeader="false"
        placement="Bottom">
        <TextArea value="{Comments}" growing="true" growingMaxLines="4" width="100%"/>
    </Popover>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I supposed that "{Comments}" is the right way of calling poperty of list items.

It seems that I'm wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the `Comments` property belongs to an entity of the `SelectExpenseDetails` entity set. The problem that you are facing is in fact because of an incorrect binding path.

You have attached your popup as a dependent of the view itself. This means that all its relative bindings (like the one for the text area's value) will be resolved based on the binding context of the view. If the view is not bound to anything, the binding will not be resolved.

To go around this, you should bind the popup itself to the correct path, obtained from the item which was pressed. So you should adjust your event handler like so:

```js
showCommentsExpenseDetailItem: function(event){
    var popover = sap.ui.xmlfragment("la.incloud.rva.aprobaciones.view.components.popover-comment-item-detail", this);
    this.getView().addDependent(popover);
    popover.bindElement(event.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath());
    popover.openBy(event.getSource());
}
```

Also, you are creating a new popup each time you press the button, you might want to reuse the popup instead (either create it declaratively in the view or store it as a property of the controller).

Comment: For curiosity. Attaching popup as a dependant of the view is a good practice?  If not, what would be the correct way?

Comment: It is a very good practice. If you do not attach the popup / dialog as a dependent to _something_ then you will have to manage its lifecycle by your own (mainly to destroy it when you no longer need it). And the view is a good place to add it. You can also add the popup [declaratively](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/234320f8d8ee45b39c60893116d60351.html) to your control tree, but you will face this [unfixed bug](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1355) (because of it, I generally add the dialogs in the dependents aggregation of e.g. a Page control inside my view).